# Trying to find minimum value in an array and return it to main

Tags: java

Coding for a game show where 4 players guess a price of an item. Exact price is user inputted first. The way I'm setting it up to find the minimum difference between player guess price and exact price of item. The player with the minimum difference is the round winner.

```
public static int getRoundsWon(double [] guessPrice, double exactPrice) { 
    double minValue = 0;
        do {
            try {
                for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
                    minValue = (guessPrice[x] - exactPrice);
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "invalid");
            }
        } while (numRounds <=3)
```

I want to use linear search but am not sure how to. Would I do Math.min(minValue) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will perform a linear search for the (absolute) minimum difference, and it returns the 0-based index (according to the guessPrice array) of the winner.
The absolute difference means that the difference can be negative or positive, ma only its absolute value it is considered.

```
public static int getRoundsWon(double[] guessPrice, double exactPrice) {
        //first set (temporary) the first player as the winner (and its difference as the minimum)
        double minValue = Math.abs(exactPrice-guessPrice[0]);
        int roundWinner = 0;
        for (int k=1;k<guessPrice.length;k++) {  //then check for all other players
            double diff = Math.abs(exactPrice-guessPrice[k]);
            if (diff<minValue) { //if we found a new minimum
                minValue=diff; //store the new minimum
                roundWinner=k; //and set the new temporary winner
            }
        }
        return roundWinner; //return the actual winner
    }
```

The method requires that the length of the guessPrice array is at least one (i.e. at least one element), but since in your game you said you have four players, this should be not a problem.

Comment: I want to make sure I understand this correctly. So for the first line, you are declaring that the min value is presently at index 0 and then for double diff, you find the difference for each element. The if statement then finds that if another value is smaller than the minValue, then it becomes the new minimum value?

edit: I just saw your documentation, thank you so much!

Comment: exactly... other approaches to search a minimum is to set no winner at the beginning, and set the minimum value as the most great possible value, i.e. double minValue= Double.MAX_VALUE; and then start the for loop from index zero (and not one as in my code). But I find that the first approach is more conceptually right, but also the second approach is in practice correct.

Comment: If you don't mind answering another question. Only one player wins a round. They receive prizes based on the number of rounds won. I want to keep track of each player round win record. I was thinking of creating a winnersCount counter array and from the code above, say the winner was at index [2], then i'd want to increment winnersCount at index [2] as well. How do i go about doing that?

Comment: You create the array: int[] winnersCount = new int[noumberOfPlayers]; this initializes all the counts at zero, then you call the method and store the index of the winner: int roundWinner= getRoundsWon(...); and you increase the counter of that index: winnersCount[roundWinner]++; and you do that for each round (probably you are in a loop)

Comment: And if I wanted to output this using JOptionPane.showMessage dialog?
Part of the code involves giving each player a prize based on the rounds won. So for my pseudocode I have IF roundsWon = 1 THEN prize won: $15,125.
When i try the same idea in java it gives me the error "incomparable types" since its comparing int and int[]
I initialized the prizes as int prizeWon = 0;

Answer (score 0):

I think what you'd want to do in this situation is store the difference between the players guess and the exact price in a temp variable in the loop body and then check if that value is less than the current minimum, in which case you would replace the minimum with the temp value. I would use a sentinel as the initial value of minimum, something like Integer.Max_VALUE so that the player's guesses would always be less than the initial value of minimum.

```
// set minValue to largest possible value of double
double minValue = Double.MAX_VALUE;
for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++ ){
    // set temp to difference between user's guess and exact price
    double temp = Math.abs(exactValue - userGuess);
    // set minValue to minimum of previous minValue or userGuess
    minValue = Math.min(minValue, temp);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I should have mentioned that I'm a beginner at java. I kind of understand what you are saying but by storing the values in a temp variable, what do you exactly mean? Aren't the values being stored in "minValue"? Could you show me an example?

Answer (score 0):

As you suggested, i am using a linear search, and setting the initial minimum value to the maximum value of a double, making sure that it will be replaced by the first guess price.
I am also returning a winner index of -1 if the array of guess prices is empty, letting you handle that error (instead of throwing or catching exceptions)

```
int winnerIndex = -1;
double minDifference = Double.MAX_VALUE;

for(int i = 1; i < guessPrices.length; i++) {
   double temp = guessPrices[i] - exactPrice;
   if(temp < minDifference) {
        minDifference = temp;
        winnerIndex = i;
   }
}

return winnerIndex;
```

Comment: Instead of just delivering code to the author, please elaborate on your answer, explaining what you did and how this will resolve the question at hand.

Comment: My bad, edited with a brief summary of what I have done.
Thanks